# sending on_failure email in prefect.io

Tags: python, prefect

I am trying to send myself an email whenever a task fails but I am having some issues. Here is my code for context:

**failure_notification_task.py**

```
from prefect_email import email_send_message, EmailServerCredentials
from prefect import task
from dotenv import dotenv_values

def send_failure_email(email_address):
    try:
        email_server_credentials = EmailServerCredentials.load("google-email")
    except:
        env_vars = dotenv_values()
        credentials = EmailServerCredentials(
            username=env_vars.get('GOOGLE_EMAIL_ADDRESS'),
            password=env_vars.get('GOOGLE_APP_PASS'),
        )
        credentials.save("google-email", overwrite=True)
        email_server_credentials = EmailServerCredentials.load("google-email")

    email_send_message.with_options(name=f"email {email_address}").submit(
        email_server_credentials=email_server_credentials,
        subject="Pipeline Failure Notification",
        msg=f"this task has encountered a failure.",
        email_to=email_address,
    )

@task()
def failed_task():
    raise ValueError
```

**main.py**

```
from prefect import Flow
from tasks.weather_api_task import fetch_weather_api, format_responses
from tasks.azure_blob_task import connect_to_blob, get_container, upload_blob
from tasks.failure_notification_task import failed_task, send_failure_email
from dotenv import dotenv_values
from datetime import datetime

# Load environment variables from the .env file
env_vars = dotenv_values()

# Retrieve the values using the keys
weather_api_key = env_vars.get('WEATHER_API_KEY')
storage_account_key = env_vars.get('AZURE_STORAGE_KEY')
storage_account_name = env_vars.get('ACCOUNT_NAME')

# Set url and location parameter
url = "http://api.weatherstack.com/current"
locations = ["Raleigh, United States", "Halifax, Canada", "Mumbai, India"]

# Set container name
container_name = "jistpoc"

# Set blob name
now = datetime.now()
now_str = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
blob_name = "weather_data_" + now_str

#if failed_task fails then send this email to this address
failed_task.on_failure(send_failure_email('fakeemail@gmail.com'))

# Define the weather_flow
@Flow
def weather_flow():
    responses = fetch_weather_api(url=url, weather_api_key=weather_api_key, locations=locations)
    blob_data = format_responses(responses=responses)
    blob_service_client = connect_to_blob(storage_account_name=storage_account_name, storage_account_key=storage_account_key)
    container_client = get_container(blob_service_client=blob_service_client, container_name=container_name)
    upload_blob(container_client=container_client, blob_data=blob_data, blob_name=blob_name)
    failed_task()
    


# Run the weather_flow
weather_flow._run()
```

I created a fake task called failed_task that raises an error and then I use this line to email myself on failure:

```
#if failed_task fails then send this email to this address
failed_task.on_failure(send_failure_email('fakeemail@gmail.com'))
```

I keep getting this error though:

*RuntimeError: Tasks cannot be run outside of a flow. To call the underlying task function outside of a flow use `task.fn()`.*

I have been banging my head against a wall trying to solve this. Can anyone with knowledge of prefect.io be of assistance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your error message looks like it is one found in Prefect 2. But it looks like you are importing @Flow as a class instead of using the @flow
(lowercase) decorator used in Prefect 2. You can check out the [Prefect docs on flows](https://docs.prefect.io/2.10.12/concepts/flows/) for more info.

Beyond that, I would cut `).submit(` in the section below. Assuming you are running a relatively recent version of Prefect 2, you don't need `.submit` unless submitting a task to a task runner.

```py
    email_send_message.with_options(name=f"email {email_address}").submit(
        email_server_credentials=email_server_credentials,
        subject="Pipeline Failure Notification",
        msg=f"this task has encountered a failure.",
        email_to=email_address,
    )
```

The `email_send_message` is a task, so you do need to call it within a flow.

Finally, you want to just call the weather_flow function like this: `weather_flow()` (or in an `if __name__=="__main__":` block).